# Backporting a git branch with rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

Let's take the following scenario into consideration

```
    m1-m2------m3-------m4--------m5 (master)
        \                \
         \                \
          \                \---f1-f2-f3(feature)
           \                \
            \                \-P1-P2-P3(patch)
             \
              \
               r1-r2-r3-r4 (release)
```

`Master` is at `m5` commit as people are contributing, and `release` is at `r4` after a certain release has been done.

Now I found a bug in the application that applies to all the versions. For some reason I fork a branch from `m4` (why not `m5`? It's realistic to say that `m5` was not commited yet at that moment) and fix the problem with P1..P3.

Satisfied for the work done I merge the patch into `m5` but I am asked to backport the patch to `release` and produce an update.

```
    m1-m2------m3-------m4--------m5-----------m6 (master)
        \                \                    /
         \                \                  /
          \                \-P1-P2-P3(patch)/
           \                \
            \                \                  
             \                \---f1-f2-f3(feature)
              \
               r1-r2-r3-r4 (release)
```

If `patch` was made of as single commit, I would easily do

```
git checkout release
git cherry-pick patch
```

Okay, but `patch` is a series of commit. I think I should rebase.

The problem is that rebasing `patch` onto `release` involves a commit, `m3`, which must not be part of the `release` branch. It could be an entire series of commits.

So the scenario is the following. I know that `feature` was **generated** from a specific commit (normally a tag in our workflow), so I would like to rebase all commits from `m4` (excluded) to `patch` included, pointing `release` to the new `P3'`.

I have tried to *abuse* `onto` option of rebase command, so I am asking advice here because I might have not enough understandment of the rebase command

```
git checkout release #pick r4
git branch experiment #destructive actions will try not to destroy precious branches
git checkout experiment
git rebase --onto experiment m4 patch # detaches head, but I don't want that!
```

Expected result below

```
    m1-m2------m3-------m4--------m5-----------m6 (master)
        \                \                    /
         \                \                  /
          \                \-P1-P2-P3(patch)/
           \                \
            \                \                  
             \                \---f1-f2-f3(feature)
              \
               r1-r2-r3-r4-P1'-P2'-P3' (release)
```

Question is: how do I backport those patch commit to an earlier branch without doing it interactively?

Interactively (this is an answer, actually), I **could** do the following, especially if I track commits by issue ID:

```
git rebase -i patch
##and skip all commits until m4 (included)
```

But as you can see my question is about asking for an automated way

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but maybe you can do (from r3):
`git cherry-pick m4..P3`

Comment: Why not cherry-pick all relevant commits, i.e. P1 through P3?

Comment: @rubenvb because they might be many. It is cheaper to do the interactive rebase trick rather than maually cherry-picking each and every interesting commit

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ That I don't understand. `git log`, copy paste relevant hashes, then just `git cherry-pick <ALL THE HASHES>`. I really don't see how that is "more expensive" than an interactive rebase onto a totally unrelated branch.

Comment: We programmers are lazy. If we can do something in one line of bash/code rather than doing a longer set of manual operations we are **happier** and **less prone to errors**. Plus, seeking for a "shorter way" to do a complicated thing is the main reason why we ask silly questions on stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to apply the diff between revisions `m5` and `m6`.  `git cherry-pick` can do that, with the help of the `-m` option:

> **-m** *parent-number*, **--mainline** *parent-number*
>
> Usually you cannot cherry-pick a merge because you do not know which side of
>   the merge should be considered the mainline. This option specifies the parent
>   number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows cherry-pick to replay the
>   change relative to the specified parent.

Thus the steps are as follows:

1. Run `git show m6` and note the (1-based) index **k** of `m5` on the `Merge:` line.
2. `git cherry-pick -m` **k** `m6`

Comment: can you elaborate what the "(1-based) index k" is?

Comment: @BryceDrew If `git show m6` reports '`Merge: m5 P3`', then k=1, otherwise (in case of '`Merge: P3 m5`') - k=2. 1-based means that counting starts from 1, rather than from 0.

Comment: Doesn't OP want P1-P2-P3 and not any of the new master commits?

Comment: @BryceDrew This will apply P1-P2-P3 as a single commit

Answer (score 2):

```
#create a new branch, based on `patch` and switch to it
git checkout -b backported-patch patch
#rebase this new `backported-patch` branch onto release:
git rebase --onto release m4 backported-patch
# now we have backported patch branch, merge it into release:
git checkout release
git merge backported-patch
```

BTW, I think it's better to rebase onto mergebase of the branches, i.e. `git rebase --onto m2 m4 backported-patch`, in this case the back-ported patch will be mergeable to both of them providing cleaner history.

So, the final result will be:

```
m1-m2------m3-------m4--------m5-----------m6 (master)
    \                \                    /
     \                \                  /
      \                \-P1-P2-P3(patch)/
       \                \
        \                \                  
         \                \---f1-f2-f3(feature)
          \--P1'-P2'-P3'(backported-patch)
           \           \
            r1-r2-r3-r4-M (release)
```

Also, it is bad idea to have unmerged release branch changes, i.e. r1-r4 commits should be merged to master branch, - makes history cleaner.

It gives you:

```
m1-m2------m3-------m4--------m5-----------m6-----m7 (master)
    \                \                    /      /
     \                \                  /       |
      \                \-P1-P2-P3(patch)/        |
       \                \                        |
        \                \                       |
         \                \---f1-f2-f3(feature)  |
          \--P1'-P2'-P3'  ----------------------/
           \           \ /
            r1-r2-r3-r4-M (release)
```

Answer (score -2):

After `git rebase --onto experiment m4 patch`, you are almost there. `git checkout release;git reset P3' --hard` or `git branch -D release;git branch release P3'`.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ P3' not P3. I don't understand how someone can down vote me without a try.

Comment: Sorry I was convinced you mistyped P3. anyway don't forget that P3' is a sha1 hash and not a label, so you would have to find out what has does that commit have, or what label did git move to P3'. That might be the cause of downvoting. But from my point of view you are also right because if rebase onto experiment will overwrite patch (thus lose P3) then I can reset release to P3' which coincides with patch

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ after the onto rebase, right in the detached HEAD state, you could run `git log -1 --pretty=%h` to get P3' sha1.  P3' represents the right branch you are expecting. So why not just move the ref `release` to it? Every commit along with its ancestors is a branch, nameless till we make a ref, which could be a tag or a branch, point to it.